# Testing AngularJS module with Jasmine causes Jasmine error

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am unable to get a simple Jasmine test to work on my AngularJS module.  Any advice would be very much appreciated.

Module with controller:

```
(function(myApp) {
    myApp.App = angular.module("MyApp", []).
    config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', { controller: "CoreAppController", templateUrl: 'App.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);

    myApp.App.controller("CoreAppController", function($scope, $http, widgetService)     {
        /* controller definition */
    }
}(window.myApp = window.myApp || {}));
```

Unit test:

```
(function(myApp) {
    describe("CoreAppController spec", function() {
        describe("Create the CoreApp", function() {
            beforeEach(angular.module("MyApp"));
            describe("CoreAppController", function() {
                it("Should create the core application",
                    expect(1).toBeGreaterThan(0)
                )
            });
        })
    });
}(window.myApp = window.myApp || {}));
```

Files included in the test file are in this order:

- jasmine.js
- jasmine-html.js
- angular.min.js
- angular.mock.js
- app.js (contains the module and controller definition)
- CoreAppControllerSpec.js (unit test file).

Running this test results in the following error:

TypeError: Object # has no method 'apply'
    at jasmine.Block.execute (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:1064:17)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2049:8)
    at jasmine.Spec.execute (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2376:14)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2049:8)
    at jasmine.Suite.execute (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2521:14)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2049:8)
    at jasmine.Suite.execute (file:///C:/TeamFoundation/PRE/test/jasmine/jasmine.js:2521:14)

Removing the 'module' line from the test causes it to pass.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Removed the 'myApp' anonymous function wrap and changed the code to adding the controller direct to angular.module("MyApp"), and still, the unit test fails with the same error.

Answer (score 5):

[angular.module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module) creates a new module.

[module](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.module) is an alias for angular.mock.module - published on window for easy access - which collects the module's configuration.

That's why changing angular.module to module solved your problem.

Regards,
Eitan

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, changing 'angular.module' to just 'module' solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

A better solution is to include `angular-mocks.js` just after the `angular.js` script, so that angular-mocks will define `window.module = angular.mock.module = ...` (as well as `window.inject`, and so on ...).