# How to correct this AngularJS Karma test setup filter injection

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, angularjs-filter

I have been learning AngularJS and the time has come to start writing tests but I'm falling at the first hurdle.

My karma config file is:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '..',

    // frameworks to use
    frameworks: ['mocha'],

    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'node_modules/chai/chai.js',
      'public/js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js',
      'public/js/libs/angular.js',
      'test/libs/angular-mocks.js',
      'public/js/**/*.js',
      'test/angular/**/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I have a filter declared:

```
angular.module('timeMachine.filters',[])
  .filter('hours', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input == 1
      ? '1 hour'
      : input + ' hours';
  }
});
```

And a test:

```
var should = chai.should();

describe("The hours filter", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {
      angular.module('timeMachine.filters');
    });

    it('should be able to test', function(){
      true.should.equal(true);
    });

    it('should be able to inject an hours filter', inject(function($filter) {
      var hours = $filter('hours');
      expect(hours).not.to.equal(null);
    }));
});
```

However, the second test fails with the message:

> [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: hoursFilterProvider <- hoursFilter

In the context of the running Angular app this filter works.

I assume I'm missing something through inexperience and any help would be awesome!

Comment: I'm not to good with testing yet but egghead.io has a bunch of tutorials on this that might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using angular.mock.module in the test.
See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14750425/testing-angularjs-module-with-jasmine-causes-jasmine-error/15229014#15229014)

Comment: Ah, I thought including angular-mocks.js after angular.js would have me covered. I'll try this shortly... thanks!

Comment: If you're ever in Manchester I owe you a hug! That worked perfectly.